# expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant...I'm getting this error in my C program

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

This is the C program i have written
based on a previous answer i have changed the varibale name to arrSize from SIZE, but it still shows error while compiling the code

line:4  column:17   [Error] expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define arrSize 8 //I'm getting error in this line

void merge(int a[], int temp[], int left, int mid, int right);
void display(int [], int);
void msort(int [], int [], int, int);
void merge_sort(int [], const int);

int main() {
    int a[arrSize] = {-1, 2, 9, 1, 7, 2, 5, 0};
    int temp[arrSize];
    printf("Array before sorting:\n");
    display(a, arrSize);
    merge_sort(a, arrSize);
    printf("Array after sorting:\n");
    display(a, arrSize);
    return 0;
}

void merge_sort(int a[], int temp[], const int arrSize) {
    msort(a, temp, 0, arrSize-1);
}

void display(int a[], const int arrSize) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the full error message, and indicate, if needed, what line in the code it corresponds to - indeed, there is more than one line of errors - please [see here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJm3E1zID).

Comment: `const int arrSize` - The preprocessor always runs first. It does token substitution, so this becomes `const int 8`. That's why naming conventions exist that partition macros and regular identifiers.

Comment: `void merge_sort(int [], const int);` You are "lying" to your compiler about parameters. That should result in an error message when the compiler sees the implementation of `merge_sort` later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're trying to create a MACRO called `arrSize`, and again you try to use a variable of the same name in the same namespace.

The preprocessor replacement based on the macro names creates invalid syntax in the function `merge_sort()` using the variable of same name (identifier).

Either change the macro name, or change the variable name used in the function.

And also, double-check the function prototype and definition — there's a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't name macros and variables the same name. `#define arrSize` ... `const int arrSize`.
- merge_sort declaration and definition mismatch.

So the line `void merge_sort(int a[], int temp[], const int arrSize)` is the source of all problems.

Comment: So, how can i use arrSize in functions ?

Comment: @Flame Pass it as a parameter like you do, but give your parameters some other meaningful name.

Comment: @Flame a very common naming convention suggests using capital letters only (and underscores) for macro identifiers so that they will never collide with variable/parameters names (mixed lower and uppers cases). Change it to `#define ARR_SIZE 8` and you 'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

You are using parameter names that coincide with the constant name

```
#define arrSize 8
```

as for example

```
void merge_sort(int a[], int temp[], const int arrSize) {
                                               ^^^^^^^
```

After the preprocessing phase the compiler considers this declaration like

```
void merge_sort(int a[], int temp[], const int 8) {
                                              ^^^
```

So either change parameter names or change the name of the constant.

It is a good idea to assign names for manifest constants that are built from all upper case letters. For example

```
#define ARR_SIZE 8
```